# Where clause in Dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to get all the tables where bank_id is 01.
I have written the following block

```
DECLARE

 cursor cBankId is
     select owner||'.'||table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'BANK_ID';
        v_table     all_tab_columns.table_name%TYPE;
        vcount varchar2(50);

BEGIN

     open cBankId;
    loop
        fetch cBankId into v_table;
        exit when cBankId%notfound;

execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || v_table into vcount || ' where bank_id  = 01';


IF vcount > 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_table);
END IF;

end loop;
    close cBankId;

END;
```

I want to know how to put where clause in the execute immediate statement .
I am getting the error
ORA-06550: line 15, column 67:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "|" when expecting one of the following:

. ( , % ; return returning using

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change the order you're writing the parts of your query.
When using dynamic SQL, you need something like this:

```
SQL> declare
  2      v_table varchar2(30);
  3      vCount  number;
  4  begin
  5      v_table := 'dual';
  6      execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || v_table  || ' where 1=1' into vcount;
  7      --
  8      dbms_output.put_line('vCount: ' || vCount);
  9  end;
 10
 11  /
vCount: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

That is: `execute immediate 'select ... from ... where ...' INTO ...;`

Answer (score -1):

You can't dynamically use a variable for the table name, instead use:

```
DECLARE

cursor cBankId is
 select owner||'.'||table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'BANK_ID';
    v_table     all_tab_columns.table_name%TYPE;
    vcount varchar2(50);
    v_sql varchar2(1000);


BEGIN

 open cBankId;
loop
    fetch cBankId into v_table;
    exit when cBankId%notfound;

v_sql := 'select count(*) from ' || v_table || ' into vcount where bank_id  = 01';   

execute immediate v_sql;

IF vcount > 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_table);
END IF;

end loop;
    close cBankId;

END;
```

Comment: You can use a variable for the table name. Also, does this work?